# Exception not thrown

Tags: c#, exception

```
 try
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://facebook.com");
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

    MessageBox.Show("I am here!");      // Not run                
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Error Occurred!"); //Not run!
}
```

In my country facebook is filtered and When I run this code, no exceptions will be throw, also program not display message "I am here!";
What happened?

I want to use this code in a timer_tick every 1 minute and update ui label with alive status. do you have alternative way?

Comment: What do you mean by "filtered"? What do you see if you enter the URL into a browser?

Comment: One of the MessageBox.Show() should be called, so it would appear they are not doing what you expect them to do. Can you put a breakpoint on them both to see which is called? 
Depending on how the filtering is done it is possible that an exception will not be thrown even though you cannot access the website.

Comment: What makes you think it *should* throw an exception? Just because the site is blocked, doesn't mean the entire request fails. It's likely the request is redirected to a 'blocked' page, and/or the HTTPStatus code is not 200

Comment: Is this code is in a new thread ?

Comment: If you debug this, are you able to step beyond the `GetResponse()`-call? Maybe this does simply result into an endless request.

Answer (score 0):

i guess interval value of your timer_tick() is less than default timeout value for web request and then next timer round executed before current round completion. therefore **use a timeout for your request** also it's better to use Task to don't freeze ui when running timer.

```
Task task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://facebook.com");
    request.Timeout = 5000;
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();

});

// Run this code after successfully completing the task...
task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
   websiteIsAvailable = true;
   //Some code...
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion);

// Run this code after task Failure...
task.ContinueWith(t =>
{
   websiteIsAvailable = false;
   //Some code...
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);
```